# The isotopy class of a Boothby-Wang contact structure

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, symplectic-topology, contact-geometry

Let $p:\Sigma\to M$ be a non-trivial principal $S^1$-bundle over a closed orientable surface $M$. Let's call $V$ the vector field generating the $S^1$-action. It is known that there exists a Boothby-Wang contact form $\alpha$ on $\Sigma$, namely, $\alpha(V)=1$ and $d\alpha=p^*\omega$ for a symplectic form $\omega$ on $M$. Let $\xi_+$ be the co-oriented contact structure associated to $\alpha$ and let $\xi_-$ be the one associated to $-\alpha$.

**Question.** Is it true that if $\Sigma\neq S^3,\mathbb R\mathbb P^3$, then $\xi_-$ and $\xi_+$ are not contact isotopic?

Comment: See Corollary 4.10 of Gompf's [Handlebody Construction of Stein Surfaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9803019).

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference @magicker72. Actually, Corollary 4.10 deals with the homotopy of $\xi_+$ and $\xi_-$ as plane fields and not with contact isotopies.